# NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays in HTML

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to call a very simple HTTP GET method from a service. The method works correctly, as I can see the data array in the browser's console.

service:

```
export class ApiService {
  PHP_API_SERVER = 'http://localhost/dev/backend';

  listArticles(): Observable<Article[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Article[]>(`${this.PHP_API_SERVER}/list.php`);
  }

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

}
```

component:
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

```
  artikel: Article[];

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService.listArticles().subscribe((artikel: Article[]) => {
      this.artikel = artikel;
      console.log(this.artikel);
    })
  }
```

component-HTML:

```
... div *ngFor="let article of artikel"
```

ERROR (in browser):
HomeComponent.html:4 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

As far I can see, "artikel" IS an array, but the runtime keeps telling me it's not. Am I missing some type cast?

Comment: what does the log output show?

Comment: Show the output of `console.log(this.artikel);`

Comment: initialize the `artikel: Article[];` so change it to `artikel: Article[] = []`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The http call is async so before the subscribe gets called, the html is rendered with:
artikel: Article[] which is an array but not initialized.

Try adding:

```
artikel: Article[] = [];
```

This way, the first time its rendered it wont crash and its going to be updated when your data arrives.